# Writing less unnecessary code with WordPress

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop

I've got a simple homepage, that pulls content for 4 different categories. To do this, I'm writing 4 different WP_Query, and only the category name is changing (and as a result, the WP_Query name, etc).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is it possible to put WP_Query inside a foreach loop — or is there a better way of just renaming variables rather than writing WP_Query 4 times?

Here is an example of the code. This is repeated 4 times, with just the 'category_name' changing, along with some variable names:

```
<?php
$fashion_cat = array(
    'category_name' => 'fashion',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in' => $already_posted,
    'category__not_in' => $private_categories
);

$fashion_query = new WP_Query( $fashion_cat );
if ( $fashion_query->have_posts() ):
    $i = 0;
while ( $fashion_query->have_posts() ):
    $fashion_query->the_post();
    $images = get_field( 'gallery' );
if ( $images ):
$i++;
?>

<?php  if ( $i == 1 ): ?>
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="img-ctnr">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="col-2">

<?php elseif ( $i == 2 || $i == 3 ): ?>
        <div class="img-ctnr-small">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
        </div>

<?php elseif ( $i == 4 ): ?>
                <div class="img-ctnr-med">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
                </div>

<?php
endif;
endif;
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

And this is my attempt at putting it into a foreach loop, but it only calls once:

```
<?php
$home_cats = array( 'fashion', 'beauty', 'lifestyle' );
foreach ( $home_cats as $key ):
    echo $key;

$key_cat = array(
    'category_name' => $key,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in' => $already_posted,
    'category__not_in' => $private_categories
);

$key_query = new WP_Query( $key_cat );
if ( $key_query->have_posts() ):
    $i = 0;
while ( $key_query->have_posts() ):
    $key_query->the_post();
$images = get_field( 'gallery' );
if ( $images ):
    $i++;
if ( $i == 1 ): ?>
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="img-ctnr">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="col-2">

<?php elseif ( $i == 2 || $i == 3 ): ?>
        <div class="img-ctnr-small">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
        </div>

<?php elseif ( $i == 4 ): ?>
                <div class="img-ctnr-med">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $images[0]['url'];?>"></a>
<?php top_note(); ?>
                </div>

<?php
endif;
endif;
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: Can you add your code please.

Comment: How do you feel about Loops?...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function cat_loop ($key){
    $fashion_cat = array(
        'category_name' => $key,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post__not_in' => $already_posted,
        'category__not_in' => $private_categories
    );

    // Add the loop.
}

cat_loop ('fashion');
cat_loop ('beauty');
cat_loop ('lifestyle');
```

put the loop in function which has variable for the  `category_name` and repeat it.
I hope this helps